# Python float to string (scientific notation), in specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

This is a very specific question, but despite a large number of online resources I cannot seem to find a function which does what I want. Assume I have an arbitrary float, say for example "2.". I want to convert the float into the following format:

```
'2.000000E+000'
```

That is to say: 8 digits before the exponential, and 3 digits (four counting the sign) after the exponential. There are a few functions which almost (but not quite) yield the desired output. Using

```
"%.6e" %float(2)
```

yields the output

```
'2.000000e+00'
```

Which permits me to specify how many digits I have to **before** the exponential, but not after - it always gives me two digits. The function numpy.format_float_scientific, on the other hand:

```
numpy.format_float_scientific(2.0000000000, exp_digits=3,precision=6)
Out[30]: '2.e+000'
```

permits me to specify the number of digits **after** the exponential, but not before. I would like to do both. Do you know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with `unique` to `False` for `numpy`:

```
numpy.format_float_scientific(2.0000000000, unique=False, exp_digits=3,precision=6)
```

Output:

```
'2.000000e+000'
```

Comment: Ah, that's it, what a simple solution - thank you very much!